# N-body simulation in javascript

Tags: javascript, simulation, physics, simulator, gravity

I am working on a n-body gravity simulation in javascript and pixijs. 
But there is one major problem. When two objects are orbiting around each other they come steadily closer to each other. And when they are too close they start accelerating really fast in a specific direction.

You can view my project here: https://github.com/ruttydm/gravity
And you can view the example here http://infinidum.com/gravity/

Comment: You need to compute first all the forces and then with all forces for the current state fixed you do the velocity and position updates. If done right this is symplectic Euler and if the time step is small enough this will even be qualitatively close to the physical behavior. Check out Verlet and higher order symplectic methods.

Comment: @LutzL Oh, thank you, i will try it.

Comment: See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22750357/1374437) for an implementation of the Velocity Verlet integration method. The code is in C++ and is trivially translated into JS.